# How to fill an image I made on tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

So first of all I would like to say that I'm still learning how to use tikz, so I'm aware that the figure I made could be made simpler. I would like to know how to fill in the figure I made.

Here is the code:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \node (a0) at (-1.85,-3.7) {\scriptsize $a_0$};
        \node (a2) at (-1.25,-3.7) {\scriptsize $a_2$};
        \node (a4) at (-0.65,-3.7) {\scriptsize $a_4$};
        \node (a6) at (-0.05,-3.7) {\scriptsize $a_6$};
        \node (a8) at (0.55,-3.7) {\scriptsize $a_8$};
        \node (a10) at (1.15,-3.7) {\scriptsize $a_{10}$};
        \node (a12) at (1.75,-3.7) {\scriptsize $a_{12}$};
        \node (a14) at (2.35,-3.7) {\scriptsize $a_{14}$};

        \node (a1) at (-1.55,-1.6) {\scriptsize $a_1$};
        \node (a3) at (-0.95,-1.6) {\scriptsize $a_3$};
        \node (a5) at (-0.35,-1.6) {\scriptsize $a_5$};
        \node (a7) at (0.25,-1.6) {\scriptsize $a_7$};
        \node (a9) at (0.85,-1.6) {\scriptsize $a_9$};
        \node (a11) at (1.45,-1.6) {\scriptsize $a_{11}$};
        \node (a13) at (2.05,-1.6) {\scriptsize $a_{13}$};
        \node (a15) at (2.65,-1.6) {\scriptsize $a_{15}$};
    
        \draw (3,-0.5) arc[x radius=5cm, y radius=1cm, start angle=90, end angle=180];
        
        \node (dots) at (3.5,-2) {$\cdots$};
        
        \draw (-2,-1.5) to (-2,-2.5);
        \draw (-2,-2.5) arc[x radius=0.15cm, y radius=1cm, start angle=180, end angle=360];
        \draw (-1.7,-2.5) to (-1.7,-2);
        \draw (-1.7,-2) arc[x radius=0.15cm, y radius=0.25cm, start angle=180, end angle=0];
        
        \draw (-1.4,-2) -- (-1.4,-2.5);
        \draw (-1.4,-2.5) arc[x radius=0.15cm, y radius=1cm, start angle=180, end angle=360];
        \draw (-1.1,-2) -- (-1.1,-2.5);
        \draw (-1.1,-2) arc[x radius=0.15cm, y radius=0.25cm, start angle=180, end angle=0];
        
        \draw (-0.8,-2) -- (-0.8,-2.5);
        \draw (-0.8,-2.5) arc[x radius=0.15cm, y radius=1cm, start angle=180, end angle=360];
        \draw (-0.5,-2) -- (-0.5,-2.5);
        \draw (-0.5,-2) arc[x radius=0.15cm, y radius=0.25cm, start angle=180, end angle=0];
        
        \draw (-0.2,-2) -- (-0.2,-2.5);
        \draw(-0.2,-2.5) arc[x radius=0.15cm, y radius=1cm, start angle=180, end angle=360];
        \draw (0.1,-2) -- (0.1,-2.5);
        \draw (0.1,-2) arc[x radius=0.15cm, y radius=0.25cm, start angle=180, end angle=0];
        
        \draw (0.4,-2) -- (0.4,-2.5);
        \draw (0.4,-2.5) arc[x radius=0.15cm, y radius=1cm, start angle=180, end angle=360];
        \draw (0.7,-2) -- (0.7,-2.5);
        \draw (0.7,-2) arc[x radius=0.15cm, y radius=0.25cm, start angle=180, end angle=0];
        
        \draw (1,-2) -- (1,-2.5);
        \draw (1,-2.5) arc[x radius=0.15cm, y radius=1cm, start angle=180, end angle=360];
        \draw (1.3,-2) -- (1.3,-2.5);
        \draw (1.3,-2) arc[x radius=0.15cm, y radius=0.25cm, start angle=180, end angle=0];
        
        \draw (1.6,-2) -- (1.6,-2.5);
        \draw (1.6,-2.5) arc[x radius=0.15cm, y radius=1cm, start angle=180, end angle=360];
        \draw (1.9,-2) -- (1.9,-2.5);
        \draw (1.9,-2) arc[x radius=0.15cm, y radius=0.25cm, start angle=180, end angle=0];
        
        \draw (2.2,-2) -- (2.2,-2.5);
        \draw (2.2,-2.5) arc[x radius=0.15cm, y radius=1cm, start angle=180, end angle=360];
        \draw (2.5,-2) -- (2.5,-2.5);
        \draw (2.5,-2) arc[x radius=0.15cm, y radius=0.25cm, start angle=180, end angle=0];
        
        \draw (2.8,-2) -- (2.8,-2.5);
        \draw (2.8,-2.5) arc[x radius=0.15cm, y radius=1cm, start angle=180, end angle=270];

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{Fig 2.3}
\end{figure}
```

And here the picture:

[image]

I wanted something like the image below:

[image]

PS: Yes I know, it's horrible, I did it in Paint.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @SebGlav Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You drew the whole picture in too many pieces to fill it. You have to create a path that is unique. In the following code, you can see that I defined a path, name `\mypath`, which is the entire drawing.

Filling it and drawing it can be done in a single line of code, since the filling closes automatically the path.

In order to see all the nodes, you have to draw them afterwards. Note that there would be a bit more automatized way to draw all the `a` nodes but since it's not the question, I let them like this.

[image: fill a complex region]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \def\mypath{
                (3,-0.5) arc[x radius=5cm, y radius=1cm, start angle=90, end angle=180]         
                -- (-2,-1.5)
                -- (-2,-2.5)
                arc[x radius=0.15cm, y radius=1cm, start angle=180, end angle=360]
                -- (-1.7,-2.5)
                -- (-1.7,-2)
                arc[x radius=0.15cm, y radius=0.25cm, start angle=180, end angle=0]     
                -- (-1.4,-2)
                -- (-1.4,-2.5)
                arc[x radius=0.15cm, y radius=1cm, start angle=180, end angle=360]
                -- (-1.1,-2.5) 
                -- (-1.1,-2)                
                arc[x radius=0.15cm, y radius=0.25cm, start angle=180, end angle=0]
                -- (-0.8,-2)
                -- (-0.8,-2.5)
                arc[x radius=0.15cm, y radius=1cm, start angle=180, end angle=360]
                -- (-0.5,-2.5)
                -- (-0.5,-2)
                arc[x radius=0.15cm, y radius=0.25cm, start angle=180, end angle=0]
                -- (-0.2,-2)
                -- (-0.2,-2.5)
                arc[x radius=0.15cm, y radius=1cm, start angle=180, end angle=360]
                -- (0.1,-2.5)
                --(0.1,-2)
                arc[x radius=0.15cm, y radius=0.25cm, start angle=180, end angle=0]
                -- (0.4,-2)
                -- (0.4,-2.5)
                arc[x radius=0.15cm, y radius=1cm, start angle=180, end angle=360]
                -- (0.7,-2.5)
                -- (0.7,-2) 
                arc[x radius=0.15cm, y radius=0.25cm, start angle=180, end angle=0]
                -- (1,-2) 
                -- (1,-2.5)
                arc[x radius=0.15cm, y radius=1cm, start angle=180, end angle=360]
                -- (1.3,-2.5)
                -- (1.3,-2) 
                arc[x radius=0.15cm, y radius=0.25cm, start angle=180, end angle=0]
                -- (1.6,-2)
                -- (1.6,-2.5)
                arc[x radius=0.15cm, y radius=1cm, start angle=180, end angle=360]
                -- (1.9,-2.5)
                -- (1.9,-2)
                arc[x radius=0.15cm, y radius=0.25cm, start angle=180, end angle=0]
                -- (2.2,-2) 
                -- (2.2,-2.5)
                arc[x radius=0.15cm, y radius=1cm, start angle=180, end angle=360]
                -- (2.5,-2.5)
                -- (2.5,-2)
                arc[x radius=0.15cm, y radius=0.25cm, start angle=180, end angle=0]
                -- (2.8,-2) 
                arc[x radius=0.15cm, y radius=1cm, start angle=180, end angle=270]}
                
                \draw[fill=orange!50] \mypath;  

        \node (a0) at (-1.85,-3.7) {\scriptsize $a_0$};
        \node (a2) at (-1.25,-3.7) {\scriptsize $a_2$};
        \node (a4) at (-0.65,-3.7) {\scriptsize $a_4$};
        \node (a6) at (-0.05,-3.7) {\scriptsize $a_6$};
        \node (a8) at (0.55,-3.7) {\scriptsize $a_8$};
        \node (a10) at (1.15,-3.7) {\scriptsize $a_{10}$};
        \node (a12) at (1.75,-3.7) {\scriptsize $a_{12}$};
        \node (a14) at (2.35,-3.7) {\scriptsize $a_{14}$};

        \node (a1) at (-1.55,-1.6) {\scriptsize $a_1$};
        \node (a3) at (-0.95,-1.6) {\scriptsize $a_3$};
        \node (a5) at (-0.35,-1.6) {\scriptsize $a_5$};
        \node (a7) at (0.25,-1.6) {\scriptsize $a_7$};
        \node (a9) at (0.85,-1.6) {\scriptsize $a_9$};
        \node (a11) at (1.45,-1.6) {\scriptsize $a_{11}$};
        \node (a13) at (2.05,-1.6) {\scriptsize $a_{13}$};
        \node (a15) at (2.65,-1.6) {\scriptsize $a_{15}$};
        
        \node (dots) at (3.5,-2) {$\cdots$};
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There's no need to repeat the path. If you do a `fill` and a `draw` on the same path then it does the fill first and then the draw. Also, when you ask tikz to fill an open path then it automatically closes it first before filling (but leaves the path open for the subsequent draw).

Comment: Yes, you're right, Andrew, I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Cool. Must admit, I'm itching to simplify that path. Looks like a candidate for a `hobby` curve ...

Comment: I was too, at least to automatize it a bit, but that was not the point.

Comment: @SebGlav Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7):

This is not an answer to the actual question (though I incorporate the solutions you've already been given), but I couldn't resist tackling that path and seeing if I could simplify its construction a little.

The peaks and troughs in the original aren't *quite* equally spaced but are close enough that I took it upon myself to make them so.  This means that they can be defined in a single foreach loop, then another loop takes care of the drawing and filling, with a final loop for the labels.  It is possible to combine the whole lot into a single command, but I think that three loops separates the stages without hugely sacrificing the conciseness of it.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/611755/86}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach[
  evaluate=\k as \xcrd using -2.25+\k*.2625,
  evaluate=\k as \ycrd using {-1.15 + 1.55*mod(\k,2)}
] \k in {0,1,...,16} {
  \coordinate (a\k) at (\xcrd,\ycrd);
}

\draw[fill=violet!50] (2.05,1.5) .. controls +(175:1.5) and +(80:.5) ..
(-2.4,.7) .. controls +(-90:1) and +(-.25,0) .. (a0)
foreach \k in {1,...,16} {
   .. controls +(.25,0) and +(-.25,0) .. (a\k)
};

\foreach[evaluate=\k as \pos using {mod(\k,2) == 0 ? "below" : "above"} ] \k in {0,1,...,15} {
  \node[\pos,scale=.6] at (a\k) {\(a_{\k}\)};
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Simplified version of the path]

For completeness, here's the all-in-one-line:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
%\yrl{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/611755/86}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[fill=violet!50] (2.05,1.5) .. controls +(175:1.5) and +(80:.5) ..
(-2.4,.7) .. controls +(-90:1) and +(-.25,0) .. (-2.25,-1.15) node[below,scale=.6] {\(a_{0}\)}
foreach[
  evaluate=\k as \xcrd using -2.25+\k*.2625,
  evaluate=\k as \ycrd using {-1.15 + 1.55*mod(\k,2)},
  evaluate=\k as \pos using {mod(\k,2) == 0 ? "below" : "above"}
]\k in {1,...,16} {
   .. controls +(.25,0) and +(-.25,0) .. (\xcrd,\ycrd) node[\pos,scale=.6] {\(a_{\k}\)}
};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

This one-line code is simpler!

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=violet!50,nodes={scale=.6}] 
(2.05,1.5)
.. controls +(175:1.5) and +(80:.5) .. (-2.4,.7) 
.. controls +(-90:1) and +(180:.2) .. (-2.25,-1.15) node[below]{$a_0$}
.. controls +(0:.2) and +(180:.3) .. (-2,.4) node[above]{$a_1$}
.. controls +(0:.3) and +(180:.3) .. (-1.72,-1.15) node[below]{$a_2$}
.. controls +(0:.2) and +(180:.3) .. (-1.47,.4) node[above]{$a_3$}
.. controls +(0:.3) and +(180:.3) .. (-1.2,-1.15) node[below]{$a_4$}
.. controls +(0:.2) and +(180:.3) .. (-.92,.4) node[above]{$a_5$}
.. controls +(0:.3) and +(180:.3) .. (-.67,-1.15) node[below]{$a_6$}
.. controls +(0:.2) and +(180:.3) .. (-.4,.4) node[above]{$a_7$}
.. controls +(0:.3) and +(180:.2) .. (-.15,-1.15) node[below]{$a_8$}
.. controls +(0:.2) and +(180:.3) .. (.15,.4) node[above]{$a_9$}
.. controls +(0:.3) and +(180:.3) .. (.4,-1.15) node[below]{$a_{10}$}
.. controls +(0:.2) and +(180:.3) .. (.67,.4) node[above]{$a_{11}$}
.. controls +(0:.3) and +(180:.3) .. (.95,-1.15) node[below]{$a_{12}$}
.. controls +(0:.2) and +(180:.3) .. (1.2,.4) node[above]{$a_{13}$}
.. controls +(0:.2) and +(180:.2) .. (1.45,-1.15) node[below]{$a_{14}$}
.. controls +(0:.2) and +(180:.3) .. (1.75,.4) node[above]{$a_{15}$}
.. controls +(0:.2) and +(180:.3) .. (2.05,-1.15)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```